# Leaflet MarkerCluster stop auto re-clustering when zooming

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

When you zoom in and out, the markerclusters automatically "re-cluster", as in it calculates clustering again.

Is there an option for to disable the auto re-cluster when the zoom is changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an option for to disable the auto re-cluster when the zoom is changed?

No.

In [Leaflet.MarkerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster), the cluster depends on the value of the `maxClusterRadius` option, which is measured in screen pixels *at the current zoom level*.

I encourage you to have a look at the other [Leaflet plugins for clustering](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering), as some of them have clustering algorithms which do not depend on the zoom level.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve, you might be interested in [Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.Freezable) subplugin:

> When frozen / disabled, clusters will no longer split / merge on map zoom, but retain their status as if they were on the specified zoom level.

For example if you want the clusters to reflect the zoom 15 configuration:

```js
var map = L.map("map"),
  mcg = L.markerClusterGroup(options);

mcg.addLayers(arrayOfMarkers);
mcg.addTo(map);

mcg.freezeAtZoom(15);
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of that subplugin.

Comment: Let's say I don't want some markers to split, because people should not see the exact position when zooming in. Is there a way to freeze only some markers and other to split up?

Comment: @Mike: a possible solution would simply be to create only 1 Marker for those, possibly with a fake "cluster" icon and changing how clusters compute their number of children and display that number (typically using an extra Marker property instead of direct children count). But if the Client has already access to the exact positions, motivated people can still retrieve this data, so security is relatively weak. Feel free to open a new question should you need further help.